# Arduino starts up extremely slowly

Tags: arduino

I'm using an Arduino Mega 2560 to read from 8 load cells via HX711 bridges. During the troubleshooting, I realized the Arduino takes really long to startup. I tried to put some message for debugging, like:

```
void setup() {
  // initialize communication
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Comm Started");
  // initialize Pins
  pinMode(30, INPUT); // Pin 30: Strain Gauge 1, DATA channel
  pinMode(31, INPUT); // Pin 31: Strain Gauge 2, DATA channel
  /* some other codes*/
  Serial.println("Pin Mode Set");
  /* some other codes*/
  Serial.println("Starting init gauges");
}
```

When the sketch successfully loaded, I opened the Serial Monitor, then I needed to wait for 100~120 seconds before the "Comm Started" showed up, followed by the other two messages. The rest of the code is running OK after that.

I'm not sure whether it is correct but I thought `setup()` is the first thing Arduino should do when it starts after loading the sketch. Since the first thing in `setup()` is opening the comm and printing the message, it should not have any delays, right?

What could be the problem that introduce this 2-minute delay? Will it be a hardware issue (e.g. the wires I connected to the HX711s or power/ground that affects the performance) or some software bug could cause this as well?

Thank you very much.

Added info:

I put the code that prints `millis()` in every loop and a 100ms delay in `loop()`, and what I got is this:

[image: screenshot of Serial Monitor]

So it DOES start everything (including the internal clock) after the 2-minute blank.

Answer (score 0):

You need to see where this comes from, so the easiest is to start with the simplest possible setup.

Upload the following program:

```
void setup() {
    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(115200);
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
    Serial.println("Serial startup complete.");
}

void loop() {
}
```

Then disconnect the Arduino USB or any external device that might use the serial port.

Power your Arduino (not with the USB but with the power connector, so you make sure you are not connecting anything to the serial port), it will initialize the port and when it's done will light the LED in the pin 13 as an indicator

The LED should turn on almost immediately after you power the arduino, if not, there's something wrong with your board, try another one.

Otherwise start adding code until you see the delay appear and try to figure out what is causing it.